# Python path.exists False with absolute path True with Relative path

Tags: python

Os.path.exists returns false in a UNIX env with I use an absolute path to a file. This check passes when I use a relative path. Why???

```
os.path.exists('/home/my/absolute/long/path/file.txt') = False
```

But

```
os.path.exists('./long/path/file.txt') = True
```

I looked at the absolute path

```
os.path.abspath('./long/path/file.txt') = '/home/my/absolute/long/path/file.txt'
```

I've tried looking at files in my ClearCase vob and they are found:

```
os.path.exists('/vobs/another/vobfile.txt') = True
```

Comment: What does `os.path.exists(os.path.abspath('./long/path/file.txt'))` return?

Comment: I tried that as well. It returns False

Comment: @MJK It means that your current working directory is not where you think it is (i.e. it's not `/home/my/absolute`).

Comment: A `print(os.getcwd())` would confirm/refute that. Give it a try.

Comment: @dano and univerio you are correct. I wasn't in the directory I thought I was. Still getting used to Python. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I want to see the results of running this code:

```
import os
import os.path

fragment = './long/path/file.txt'
assert os.path.exists(fragment)
assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fragment))
```

I don't believe that the first assertion will pass and the second fail.